# hoptoad_notified gem won't unpack into vendor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, unpack, hoptoad

I *think* this should be working.

environment.rb

```
config.gem "hoptoad_notifer", :version => '=2.1.2'
```

list of installed gems:

```
$ gem list hoptoad_notifier

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

hoptoad_notifier (2.1.2)
```

Output of rake:gems

```
$ rake gems
(in /rails/appdir)
 - [R] hoptoad_notifier = 2.1.2

I = Installed
F = Frozen
R = Framework (loaded before rails starts)
```

Unpacking:

```
$ rake gems:unpack
(in /rails/appdir)
/rails/appdir (master)
$
#  that is, no result; immediate return
```

Why won't this gem unpack?  The app starts up and I can run `rake hoptoad:test` just fine, so it's loading okay from the system gem. I just want to vendorize everything for deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a pre-rails 1.0 app and I hadn't run `rake rails:update` recently.

I did and it added this line:

```
# boot.rb
Rails::GemDependency.add_frozen_gem_path
```

That tells Rails to check vendor/gems for frozen gems, or something.

Then I could see the gem as installed and unpack it as expected:

```
$ rake gems
(in /rails/appdir)
- [I] hoptoad_notifier = 2.1.2

$ rake gems:unpack
(in /rails/appdir)
Unpacked gem: '/rails/appdir/vendor/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.1.2'
```